# In Mac OS Sonoma, 'Permission denied' when trying to create a file in the home directory

Tags: command-line, bash, permission, zsh, sonoma

I'm on the latest Sonoma 14.2 and when in my user's home directory I cannot create a file. I have checked the rights and it looks okay. Sudo works but this is my home directory and it messes with me everytime i want to change .bash-files or .zsh-files. It also messes with homebrew installations.

Terminal and iTerm are granted full disk access.

First aid to repair permissions did nothing.

I've tried using bash and zsh.

I wonder why  ever thought it was a good idea to enforce this limitation and I cannot find a smart way around it. I just want to turn it off. If it is for security reasons I could understand that but I'm a grown up and this is my home directory. :o]

```
fredrik@interwebz:~$ pwd ; touch testfile ; ls -la | head -n 3 ; ls -lOde
/Users/fredrik
touch: testfile: Permission denied
total 168
drwxrwxrwx@  33 fredrik  staff   1.0K Dec 16 20:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     admin   160B Dec 13 13:25 ../
drwxrwxrwx@ 33 fredrik  staff  -  1.0K Dec 16 20:30 ./
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

Comment: Is this on a newly created account or did you migrate it via Migration Assistant/restore it from Time Machine?

Comment: Repair Permissions hasn't been in Disk Utility for years; and even when it was, it didn't affect the user account. It is possible to repair User permissions from Recovery, using the repairHomePermissions command, which brings up a utility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the ACL on home directories is `group:everyone deny delete`, so yours is definitively wrong.

To restore, run (split across several lines to make it easier to read on AD)

```
chmod -a \
    "group:everyone deny add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" \
    /Users/fredrik
```

The remaining `group:everyone deny delete` prevents accidential deletion of your home directory.

PS: You may want to run `sudo ls -lOde /Users/*; ls -lOde ~/*` to check whether other directories also have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you @nohillside, this helps.
I still don't know how this happened. The installation is new and I haven't meddled with the ACL earlier.
ls -lOde
drwxrwxrwx@ 33 fredrik  staff  -  1.0K Dec 18 17:51 ./
 0: group:everyone deny delete